# How to copy, change, and insert records in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique-key, dbeaver, nextval

In a PostgreSQL DB table, I need to copy a block of records from a prior month, change values in some of the columns, and append the updated records to the table. Details include:

- The key `id` is configured with `nextval` to automatically create
  unique key values
- The target records have `'200814'` in `group_tag`
- The new records need `'200911'` in `group_tag`
- Several other fields need to be updated as shown in the `SELECT`

My script so far:

```
INSERT INTO hist.group_control( 
  id,
  group_tag,
  process_sequence,
  state,
  cbsa_code,
  window_starts_on,
  preceding_group,
  preceding_origin,
  preceding_window_starts_on
)
SELECT id,
       '200911',
       1,
       state,
       cbsa_code,
       '2020-09-11',
       '200814',
       preceding_origin,
       '2020-08-14'
FROM hist.group_control WHERE group_tag='200814';
```

This generates an error:

```
SQL Error [23505]: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "group_control_pkey"
  Detail: Key (id)=(12250) already exists.
```

Records with key values up to `13008` exist. I would have expected `nextval` to determine this and start the `id` value at `13009`. I attempted to simply not include `id` in the statement thinking the `nextval` function would operate automatically, but that errored as well. Variations on the following have not worked due to the respective errors:

```
alter sequence group_control_id_seq restart with 13009;
SQL Error [42501]: ERROR: must be owner of relation group_control_id_seq

SELECT setval('group_control_id_seq', 13009, true);
SQL Error [42501]: ERROR: permission denied for sequence group_control_id_seq
```

Anyone know how to code the main statement to not generate the duplicate key or alternatively, how to tell `nextval` to start at a value of `13009`

Answer (score 0):

It appears your serial, bigserial, or generated by default. Any of these only assign the id column when it **is not specified** in the insert statement. If you specify the id column Postgres will not assign a key PK. Since you selected the id, Postgres attempted to use what you specified. Solution drop id from the insert statement.

```
INSERT INTO hist.group_control( 
  group_tag,
  process_sequence,
  state,
  cbsa_code,
  window_starts_on,
  preceding_group,
  preceding_origin,
  preceding_window_starts_on
)
SELECT '200911',
       1,
       state,
       cbsa_code,
       '2020-09-11',
       '200814',
       preceding_origin,
       '2020-08-14'
FROM hist.group_control WHERE group_tag='200814';
```

Comment: I noted that dropping `id` yielded an error: SQL Error [42501]: ERROR: permission denied for sequence likely_group_control_id_seq

Comment: That means 2 things, dropping the id was the correct solution.  However it also means you do not have the appropriate [GRANT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html) for the sequence.